# Create a function in BrightScript debugger?

Tags: debugging, brightscript

Is it possible to create a function interactively at the debugger interface?  When I enter something like

```
BrightScript Debugger> function foo()
```

I get an error like

```
Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(296)
```

I'm guessing this is because I didn't enter the rest of the function, but I'm not sure how I could enter the rest of the function in the debugger without getting this type of error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [anonymous function](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Program+Statements#ProgramStatements-AnonymousFunctions) to create a function in a debug console like this:

```
BrightScript Debugger> printFoo = function() : ? "foo" : end function
```

Thus, you can invoke "printFoo" just like any other function:

```
BrightScript Debugger> printFoo()
foo
```

Note that colon (":") here is used as a [new line symbol](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Statement+Summary) since you can't write multiline statements in the debug console.